# how to add/remove three level keywords using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i want to build a three level keywords system for every entry. As suggested i've created one table (ctypes) for categories' information and one (categories) for the relation table with entry.

```
CREATE TABLE ctypes (
cat_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cat_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
cat_level INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
parent_id INT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (cat_id),
UNIQUE (cat_name)
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
entry_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
cat_ids VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (entry_id)
);
```

then i've already build a form to collect the keywords information by checkboxs.

```
<form action="add_category.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><b>Level 1(A,B,C)</b></td>
    <td><b>Level 2(Aa,Ab,Ac)</b></td>
    <td><b>Level 3(Aa1,Aa2,Aa3)</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Aa</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="5" />Aa1<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="6" />Aa2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Ab</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="7" />Ab1</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="eid" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And i've create a relation table for the entry_id and cat_id, how to save the $cat[] data to the table?

Then, how to handle this edit(add/remove) the keywords for every entry, and how to search the entry by (1st,2nd,3rd keywords)?

Comment: do you have a reason for having 3 separate category tables instead of one that has a field to identify which group the entry belongs in?

Comment: use 3 separate category tables makes me convenient to get the 1st and 2nd category name.

Comment: You may be better off having a single table for your categories, and using a parent_id column to keep track of children.

Comment: then how handle with the category data? one entry may have multiple categories and i want to search the entries by categories.

Comment: A relational table would solve that. Typically you would have one table for all categories and an optional parent id for child categories. Then a separate entry for items. Then a bridge relational category that has entry_id and category_id.

Comment: It's technically possible that all three tables have a keyword with the same name. I don't think that's what you want :)

Comment: how can i get a list of 3rd category from one table? i need all the 3rd category names appear in the form. @KaiQing

Comment: Even if you chose to add a literal field to represent which level the category is on it is going to be more efficient than your proposed structure. Do what you wish though. It's your site.

Comment: i've taken your advice, but still long way to go……

Comment: From your question it's not entirely clear (to me) what you want. Your form suggest people are allowed to select a multitude of L1, L2 and L3 categories, while "three level keyword system" would indicate the (ultimate) selection of (a multitude of) *only* L3 categories. So, are people allowed to select categoreis of any level or just L3? And are they allowed to select multiple ones or not?

Comment: Please give us the HTML parsed version of the form, we don't need to read through your PHP code to understand your HTML.

Comment: It's already done, thanks

Comment: @CharlesBao: What is?

Comment: I've post my solution below

Comment: @vollie obviously i know what three level keyword system is. and it allows multiple keywords.

Comment: see this may help you http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. As has been pointed out, your table structure doesn't look ideal, but without knowing your exact end goal it's really hard to assist you and advise.

I think the main mystery is why you have three levels in each category, but only one checkbox for one level.

ie you have this:

```
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Aa</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="5" />Aa1<td>
</tr>
```

However, why can't I select "A" or "Aa"?

Maybe this is what you intend, or maybe (as per many of your comments) you're just trying to show a basic example of what you are trying to achieve and will change you code as necessary once you have the answer.

Also, your solution wont work as you need to create an array to insert into mysql, you're just appending to a variable, which will insert one row with the entire array data as one value.

To help you with the inputs you could do this:

```
//Initialise some things so can work with them (and no errors)
$arySqlQry = array();
$strError = FALSE;

//make sure you have posted data first
if (isset($_POST['cat']) && is_array($_POST['cat']))
  {

    foreach ($_POST['cat'] as $strCatKey => $strCatValue)
      {

        //ensure data is what you want, no SQL injection etc
        if ($strCatValue != 'Aa1'
            && $strCatValue != 'Aa2'
            && $strCatValue != 'Ab1')
          {
            $strError = TRUE;
          }
        else
          {
            //clean data and construct sql values ready for insert
            $strCatValue = mysql_real_escape_string($strCatValue);             
            $arySqlQry[] = "('".$eid."', '".$strCatValue."')";
          }

        //if we have an error in the array
        //stop the loop as further looping is pointless
        if ($strError == TRUE)
          {
            break;
          }


      }//end foreach


    //if we have a new array with results, and no errors
    //insert into DB
    //if not, this wont run and the error catch below will work
    if (!empty($arySqlQry) && $strError != TRUE)
      {
        $qryQuery = '"INSERT INTO categories (entry_id, cat_ids) 
                      VALUES '.implode(',', $arySqlQry).'"';
        $qryExecute = mysqli_query($dbc, $qryQuery);
      }


  } //end if $_POST is set and is array
else //(POST not there so is error)
  {
    $strError = TRUE;
  }

//if there are any errors
if ($strError == TRUE)
  {
    //do some error reporting
    //ie tell user nothing entered in form, and therefore nothing was saved
  }
```

You can see this working by commenting out the line with the `$qryExecute` and echoing the var `$qryQuery`, which will show you the constructed mysql query string and what it will insert into the database.

As for getting the data back, this is a simple select, using a while or grab an array and foreach etc.

As has been mentioned, but I feel it necessary again, the `mysql_` extensions are depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0, and you should consider using PDO or mysqli, with prepared statements for extra manageability and security.

Answer (score -2):

how to save the form data to the database table

```
$cats=''; 

foreach($_POST["cat"] as $key)  {
    $cats.=$key.',';
}
$q="insert into categories (entry_id, cat_ids) values ('$eid','$cats')";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
```

how to read data from database

```
$q = "select cat_ids from categories WHERE entry_id=$eid";    
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $cats = trim($row[0],',');
    $cat = explode(",",$cats);
    echo '<p>';
    foreach($cat as $key)  {
        $q = "select cat_name from ctypes where cat_id=$key";    
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
        echo "<b>".$row[0].";</b>";               
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: SQL Injection, Error suppression. Nothing personal, but this deserves every -1 you're about to get.

Comment: I just want my code looks simple and clean, showing what is critical. i get nothing meaningful from here. All done by myself but still getting -1s.

Comment: Inducing critical security flaws isn't helpful, even if clean and simple.

Comment: ensure the variable be numeric， using is_numeric.

Comment: Please follow the advice I gave you in the comment on the question. Edit your question to include the actual HTML code, and we'd be able to give you some proper answers.